# Start another app activity removing it from recents list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recents

I'm trying to start an activity of an app (that is not mine and which code I don't know and/or can't edit), from my app.

What I want to do, is that after starting that activity (let's call it `OtherAppActivity`) neither my activity (let's call it `MyAppActivity`) nor `OtherAppActivity` remain shown in the recent apps list.

My current code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
                android:name=".activities.Launch"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:theme="@style/EmptyActivity">
```

**MyAppActivity.java**

```
// Intent to launch OtherAppActivity
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(PKG, ACTIVITY);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 88);
```

I have done a lot of search, but none of the answers I have found, have worked for me.

I hope you understand what I want to do, and can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For your app, try adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to your application tag in the manifest file and for the intent try setting this flag:
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);`